# How to restrict S3 bucket access by network

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to allow public read access to my S3 bucket, except for 2 folders.

On 2 folders, I want to allow access only to visitors coming from specific networks.

Is there a way to define this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several different ways to grant access to data stored in Amazon S3:

- Permissions on the individual objects themselves (discouraged)
- **Bucket Policies** that grant access to whole buckets or directories
- **IAM User Policies** that grant permissions to specific IAM Users/Groups
- **Pre-Signed URLs** that grant temporary, time-limited access to objects (good for programmatically granting access via an application)

Your use-case would fit [Bucket Policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html).

You can **grant access to an entire Amazon S3 bucket** with a policy like this:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can **grant access based upon a range of IP addresses** like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition": {
         "IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.0/24"},
         "NotIpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.188/32"} 
      } 
    } 
  ]
}
```

Your situation, where you wish to "allow public read access to my S3 bucket, except for 2 folders" is slightly more difficult because it is an "everything except" use-case.

**Option 1: Specific folders**

- Grant public access to specific folders, AND
- Grant restricted access to specific folders

For example:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/folder1/*",
                  "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/folder2/*"]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/folder3/*",
                   "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/folder4/*"],
      "Condition": {
         "IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.0/24"} 
      } 
  ]
}
```

However, that requires that you specifically list each folder.

**Option 2: All except...**

In this rule, you grant public access, but then Deny some folders if they are not from the right IP range:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/folder3/*",
                   "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/folder4/*"],
      "Condition": {
         "NotIpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.0/24"} 
      } 
  ]
}
```

Note the use of `Deny` with `NotIpAddress`, which says that access is Denied if the request is not coming from the defined range of IP addresses.

However, `DENY` overrides `ALLOW`, so this also means that you will not be able to access the restricted buckets unless you come from that range of IP addresses -- even if your IAM User has been explicitly granted `ALLOW` permissions to do so. For example, if you are an administrator with all permissions in S3, you would still be denied access to the restricted folders if you are coming from the given IP range. Thus, it might be too restrictive for you since it affects all usage, even when accessed via the console/API.

Comment: thank you so much! that's just what I needed. so it isn't possible to restrict according to network?

Comment: What do you mean by "according to network"? To me, that means an IP address range. What is your definition?

Comment: I mean ISP. It's easier for me to specify ISPs than ranges of IP addresses.

Comment: No, there is no capability that allows you to select ISPs. Besides, there would be hundreds of them!